# Pause page execution until scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am already stuck for a couple of days with this code,  I want to delay the execution of targetObj.innerHTML until all the javascript files are loaded (there can be multiple and I actually need to check if they are loaded and not the headers added), Thanks in advance guys!

```
function addScriptTag(src) {
    var newScript;
    var loadFunc = function ()
    {
        $.holdReady(false);
    };
    newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    newScript.setAttribute('src',src);

    //Other browsers trigger this one
    if (newScript.addEventListener)
    newScript.addEventListener('load', loadFunc, false);

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
}

function parseScript(_source) {
    var source = _source;
    var scripts = source.match(/<script[^>]*src=[^>]*>/g);
    if (scripts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        src = scripts[i].match(/src=("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/);
        src = src[2] || src[3];
        if (src) {
            addScriptTag(src);
        }
    }
    }
    var scripts = new Array();

    return source;
}

function ajax_showContent(divId,ajaxIndex,url,callbackOnComplete)
{
        $.holdReady(true);
    var targetObj = document.getElementById(divId);
    targetObj.innerHTML = parseScript(dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response);
```

Comment: Ehh, `$(window).load(fn)` ?

Comment: Unless you're using AJAX loading, won't this happen anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a bit of changes, but what you're probably looking at is a recursive setTimeout loop. Instead of setting `targetObj.innerHTML = ...`, send a callback to `parseScript` that sets `targetObj.innerHTML`. Then, in `parseScript`, have a function that calls itself recursively every 10 milliseconds using `window.setTimeout`.

Each call to this internal function checks to see if your scripts have been executed. (Perhaps by having a global variable that holds the count of scripts to execute, and subtracting from that in each addScriptTag > loadFunc. Once that reaches 0, you've executed all your scripts.) If they have yet to be executed, the function just calls itself again within a window.setTimeout. If they have, your callback is executed - passing the desired value back to it.

Something like this (untested):

```
(function() {
    var scriptCount = 0;

    function addScriptTag(src) {
        var newScript;
        var loadFunc = function() {
            scriptCount--;
            $.holdReady(false);
        };
        newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        newScript.setAttribute('src', src);

        //Other browsers trigger this one
        if (newScript.addEventListener) newScript.addEventListener('load', loadFunc, false);

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
    }

    function parseScript(_source, callback) {
        var source = _source;
        var scripts = source.match(/<script[^>]*src=[^>]*>/g);
        if (scripts) {
            scriptCount = scripts.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
                src = scripts[i].match(/src=("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/);
                src = src[2] || src[3];
                if (src) {
                    addScriptTag(src);
                }
            }
            var wait = function() {
                scriptCount > 0 ? window.setTimeout(wait, 10) : callback(source);
            };
        }
        else {
            callback("");
        }
        var scripts = new Array();

        return source;
    }



    function ajax_showContent(divId, ajaxIndex, url, callbackOnComplete) {
        $.holdReady(true);
        var targetObj = document.getElementById(divId);
        parseScript(
        dynamicContent_ajaxObjects[ajaxIndex].response, function(value) {
            targetObj.innerHTML = value;
        });
    }
})();
```

...but, as pointed out, there are other libraries like require.js that might do this sort of thing for you. Also, I'm not sure if `source` is what you're really trying to return here, so it might require some modification.

Comment: Any input is better than noone! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load script dependencies asynchronously, I'd look into using an AMD library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  It will check that all scripts are loaded, and allow you to execute yoru code in a callback.